# Updating to iOS sdk 13

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I just got this message from https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=03262020b.

```
Deadline for App Updates Has Been Extended
March 26, 2020

We greatly value the worldwide developer community, and appreciate your commitment to making a difference in people’s lives through the power of technology. To accommodate developers who may need additional time to update their existing apps on the App Store, the deadline for adhering to the requirements below has been extended to June 30, 2020.

Apps for iPhone or iPad must be built with the iOS 13 SDK or later and use an Xcode storyboard to provide the app’s launch screen.

iPhone apps must support all iPhone screens and all iPad apps must support all iPad screens.

Apps for Apple Watch must be built with the watchOS 6 SDK or later.

Apps that authenticate or set up user accounts must support Sign in with Apple if required by guideline 4.8 of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Apps in the Kids category must be in full compliance with guideline 1.3 and guideline 5.1.4. of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Apps using HTML 5 must be in full compliance with guideline 4.7 sections 4, 5, and 6 of the App Store Review Guidelines.
```

I am currently using react-native 0.59 to generate my iOS and android code. What do I need to do to upgrade to iOS 13 sdk? I'm using Xcode 11.5 and targeting my builds to 10.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you installed a previous SDK in to Xcode 11.5, you are using the iOS 13 SDK. I think you are getting this message due to the other requirement: use a storyboard to provide the app’s launch screen.